# Why is the global value getting overwritten from another object?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am developing a log reader, that counts, how many errors(that were specified in yaml), appear since the last time I checked(I made a fake log write where I write every 5 seconds one of the errors to the log.)

```
      logs:
        - path: path-to-file\logname.log
          error_names:
            - Error1t
            - Error2t
            - Error3t
          interval: 10
```

The problem is that I need to create for each log a different object. And then I add that object to a taskscheduller and it rerurns that code indefinetly.

```
public void execute() throws DfException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        int logFileAmount = config.getLogs().size();
        for(int logId = 0; logId < logFileAmount; logId++){

            var logConfig = config.getLogs().get(logId);
            var logReaderRerunTime = logConfig.getInterval() * 1000;
            var errors = logConfig.getErrorNames();

            for(int errorId = 0; errorId < errors.size(); errorId++) {
                var errorText = logConfig.getErrorNames().get(errorId);
                System.out.println(errorText);
                logReader = new LogReader(errorText, registry, config);
                taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
                    try {
                        logReader.runLogReader();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }, Duration.ofMillis(logReaderRerunTime));
            }
        }
    }
```

The logic behind the class(LogReader, you can see it bellow) is this: I append to a list(listOfLogs) the log that appeared since the last time I checked, and give it one of the error strings(errorText) so that it can see how many of them are in that list, thus I can now how many new errors appeared since the last time I checked.
But for some reason my output looks

```
Error11t
Error11t 0
Error22t
Error22t 0
Error33t
Error11t 0
Error33t 0
Error22t 0
Error33t 0

 
Error33t 0
Error33t 0
Error33t 0
Error33t 3
Error33t 3
Error33t 88
```

So what happens that after initialization of the object and the first task scheduller run, the value of all the strings in the object, become overwriten by the last string I gave. Why?
Full Code:
https://pastebin.com/JHQpmgGZ

Comment: What is `logReader`? If it is a field, then each loop iteration will overwrite the previous value. The lambda passed to the scheduler captures the `logReader` variable in a closure and uses the latest value _at execution time_ (not at scheduling time). Without a [mre] (as _text_; in the question), this is just an educated guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. What was happing is that, it was not the value of the string that was being overwritten, but the object itself. This was happening because I declared "logReader", as a global variable, so instead of creating a new object every time, it just overwrote the value, of the last object. I solved this by creating a new object every time I was iterating through the errors.

```
for(int errorId = 0; errorId < errors.size(); errorId++) {

                LogReader logReader;
                String errorText = logConfig.getErrorNames().get(errorId);

                logReader = new LogReader(errorText, pathToLog, registry);
                taskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
                    try {
                        logReader.runLogReader();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }, Duration.ofMillis(logReaderRerunTime));
            }
```